# Does moisture harm a skateboard?

Tags: gear-care, rain, skateboarding

Should I be concerned if my skateboard somehow got wet? Let's say I didn't know it better and rode it in rain for example.

Comment: I doubt using it in rain will be an issue, but with any item it's probably not a good idea to leave it in the wet

Comment: I have had the wheel bearing on my boys (medium priced MGP) scooter rust and cease up. So called 'Sealed' bearing are prone to this as they have minimal amounts of grease.

Answer (score 2):

If the board is new then the main thing to worry about is the bearings. Riding through puddles increases your chance of picking up grit and other abrasives that can ruin bearings, and although many modern bearings are rust resistant, not all are.

Older boards, especially those with some damage can also allow water to soak in between the layers. This will lead to delamination, weakening the board, ruining it's springiness and eventually speeding up its demise.